# Make Sprite Fadout when defined in JSON

Tags: json, libgdx, sprite

So I'm trying to make cutscenes in JSON.
And I want to make the sprite fadeout, but only when it should.

Is there a way I can add things to Batches without putting tons of IF Statements between them, because I want to do more with Sprites from JSON.

Anybody know a method?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Actions` – a way to apply some actions one after another. See the [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Actions).

Unfortunately, they only apply to `Actors`, but you may indeed use `Image`:

```
Image image = new Image(...)
image.addAction(
    Actions.sequence(
        Actions.delay(0.5),
        Actions.moveBy(..., ...),
        Actiond.alpha(0)
    )
)
```

There's pretty much an action for everything. So, the idea is:

1. Read a json for some actions
2. Create `Actions.sequence` and put all them into it.
3. Attach the sequence to the Image.

Comment: I use Sprites and neither Actors or Images. I'm new to Libgdx and the only tutorial I could find about a Top Down RPG uses Sprites for the Player and Entities. So I have no idea how to use Images with for example TMX maps  etc.

Comment: @GigaNova simply create a `Stage`, attach an `Image` into it via `addActor` and then draw this stage using `Stage.draw()` instead of drawing sprites one by one (you're calling draw anyway). Don't forget to call `Stage.act(dt)` to make menus alive.

Comment: I've set up a new project and I've begun porting everything. Is there a way I can import TMX files and render them with the whole Stage thing?

Comment: Just call `Stage.draw` right after render of your map (I believe its sort of `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.render()`